# (Algorithm) Find if two unsorted arrays have any common elements in Θ(n*logn) time without sorting?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

We have two unsorted arrays and each array has a length of `n`. These arrays contain random integers.
How to find if these two arrays have any common elements in `Θ(n*logn)` time?

Sorting is not allowed.

Comment: have you tried anything first?

Comment: Are there any space restrictions?

Comment: With O(n) space it can be done by simply inserting all elements of one array to a set (tree) and iterating the other one while checking if some element is in there (though this is cheating, since the tree is sorted data structure...). Using a hash table instead of a tree will get you *average* case of `O(n)`.

Comment: @amit That would require a loop running for n lg n iterations afterwards to achieve Θ(n lg n) ;)

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: I have a hunch that this might not be possible without some form of sorting...

Comment: @amit A tree set can be sorting the data... because you are talking about a sorted tree...

Comment: guys my teacher told me tree not recommended for this, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Let *A* and *B* be your unsorted arrays, both of length *n*.
You may use an hash table, as suggested by @amit; however, there is an even faster algorithm.
Since *Card(A) = Card(B)*, a fast intersection algorithm is to use a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) to store the sets, and then intersection is implemented with bitwise AND operations. This still requires *O(n)*, but it is a better result with regard to constants and lower order terms hidden within the asymptotic notation.

Comment: The hash table requires O(N) steps, and you can't do better than that.

Comment: You can do better *with regard to* constants and lower order terms hidden within the asymptotic notation, while achieving the same *O(n)* upper bound.